# R - join data tables by pairs of keys

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have the following data tables:

```
> dat1
   ID1  ID2 distance
1:   1 1117  3022.22
2:   1  386 16107.74
3:   1  920 17327.00
4:   1   91 24691.42
5:   1  227 29459.34

> dat2
    ID1 ID2 common_date_begin common_date_end
1:    2   1        2000-01-01      2006-12-03
2:    3   1        2000-05-01      2006-12-03
3:    3   2        2000-05-01      2006-12-03
4: 1117   1        2000-01-01      2006-12-03
5:    4   2        2000-01-01      2006-12-03
```

`dat1` shows some meteorological stations (`ID1`), their nearest neighbor stations (`ID2`), and the distance between them.
`dat2` shows the common periods of data availability for each pair of stations. The problem is, some stations are `ID1` in `dat1` and are `ID2` in `dat2`. For example, stations `1` and `1117`.

I want to join `dat1` and `dat2` using `ID1` and `ID2` just as pairs, with no specified order. I am doing:

```
dat1[dat2, on=.(ID1, ID2), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))][,
                                                             diff_days := common_date_end - common_date_begin][]

  ID1  ID2 distance common_date_begin common_date_end diff_days
1:   1 1117  3022.22              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
2:   1  386 16107.74              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
3:   1  920 17327.00              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
4:   1   91 24691.42              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
5:   1  227 29459.34              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
```

which doesn't work, because `1` and `1117` are under distinct identifiers.
However, the result I am looking for is:

```
  ID1  ID2 distance common_date_begin common_date_end diff_days
1:   1 1117  3022.22          2000-01-01      2006-12-03 2528 days
2:   1  386 16107.74              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
3:   1  920 17327.00              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
4:   1   91 24691.42              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
5:   1  227 29459.34              <NA>            <NA>   NA days
```

Is this achievable using `data.table`?

Here is the data to reproduce my problem:

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- read.table(text="ID1  ID2 distance
1 1117 3022.22
1 386 16107.74
1 920 17327.00
1 91  24691.42
1 227 29459.34", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
dat1 <- data.table(dat1)

dat2 <- read.table(text="ID1  ID2 common_date_begin common_date_end
2    1        2000-01-01      2006-12-03
3    1        2000-05-01      2006-12-03
3    2        2000-05-01      2006-12-03
1117 1        2000-01-01      2006-12-03
4    2        2000-01-01      2006-12-03", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
dat2 <- data.table(dat2)

# convert character to dates
cols <- c("common_date_begin", "common_date_end")
dat2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: I wonder if you used your solution, and then followed it with the same command but using `.on=.(ID1=ID2, ID2=ID1), ...`.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the columns first before joining:

```
dat1[, paste0("ID", 1L:2L) := .(pmin(ID1, ID2), pmax(ID1, ID2))]
dat2[, paste0("ID", 1L:2L) := .(pmin(ID1, ID2), pmax(ID1, ID2))]
```

Comment: what `pmin` and `pmax` does?

Comment: @YOLO, its a parallelized version of `min` and `max`. so for e.g. `pmin(5:1, 1:5)` gives `c(1,2,3,2,1)`. see `?pmin` for more details